# HTML not extracted NODEJS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to scrape twitter tweets using **nodejs** and **puppeteer**

I don't want to create a developer account etc

The below code return null in scraping code. But when I write this code in twitter website it gives me HTML

```
var  html = document.querySelector('main nav').nextElementSibling;
```

Code

```
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function run() {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : false
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        // add header for the navigation requests
        page.on('request', request => {

            // Do nothing in case of non-navigation requests.
            if (!request.isNavigationRequest()) {
                request.continue();
                return;
            }

            // Add a new header for navigation request.
            const headers = request.headers();
            // headers['proxy'] = super_proxy;
            request.continue({ headers });
        });


        await page.goto("https://www.twitter.com/Udemy");

        await page.evaluate(`window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)`);
        await page.waitFor(5000);


        await page.waitFor('main nav');
        let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let results = [];

            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var  html = document.querySelector('main nav').nextElementSibling;
            var $     = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
            var html  = document.querySelector('section > div > div > div');

            //Error return empty HTML --------------------- <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            return html;
        })
        browser.close();
        return resolve(urls);
    } catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
    }
})
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Result that I want
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

> If the function passed to the page.evaluate returns a non-Serializable value, then page.evaluate resolves to undefined.

and [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args)

> The only difference between page.evaluate and page.evaluateHandle is that page.evaluateHandle returns in-page object (JSHandle).

replace `page.evaluate` with `page.evaluateHandle`:

```js
let urls = await page.evaluateHandle(() => { ... return html })
```

Comment: It could not return any html

Comment: @Adam querySelector returns an Element not an html. if you need html string of an element you need to return `html.outerHTML`. read more on them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)